# setting up subdomain in LAMP with PHP

Tags: php, lamp

is there a way to have a LAMP server and create subdomain programatically via PHP?

I don't want to install Plesk or cPanel, I know they have API's which lets me create subdomains. But is there a way to go around them and have a bare server with just LAMP services installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the mass virtual hosting module provided by Apache:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/mass.html

With your PHP, when you want to create a new domain, simply create a new directory ... and implement parts of this configuration (consult the link above) on how to configure your Apache.  This will allow a seperate vhost per host ... as opposed to the alternate answer which still requires more configuration work per unique hostname...

```
 # get the server name from the Host: header
 UseCanonicalName Off

 # this log format can be split per-virtual-host based on the first field
 LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon
 CustomLog logs/access_log vcommon

 # include the server name in the filenames used to satisfy requests
 VirtualDocumentRoot /www/hosts/%0/docs
 VirtualScriptAlias /www/hosts/%0/cgi-bin
```

Answer (score 2):

Just point all subdomains to your document root, and figure out which subdomain was accessed in your PHP code. With wildcard DNS and a wildcard virtual host, you do not need to "create" subdomains, all possible subdomains simply exist.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName *.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

This is how services that hand out a subdomain to each user work. They do not actually create DNS records, edit web server config files, and restart all their services every time a user signs up.

Comment: hmmmm, ya i did have a thought on that. When I worked with Plesk I noticed that every time a subdomain was created it added it to the vhosts.conf file, so there would be 80+ entries in there. Does Plesk restart apache everytime?

Comment: Yes it restarts apache every time.